# Graceful handling of SIGTERM (Ctrl-c) and shutdown a Threadpool

Tags: rust, concurrency

Currently, I am at the last chapter of the rust book, [implementing the graceful shutdown of the HTTP server.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html)

Now I want to extend the logic a bit and trigger the graceful shutdown after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Therefore I use the [ctrlc crate](https://crates.io/crates/ctrlc).

But I cannot make it work due to various borrowing checker errors:

```rust
fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);

    ctrlc::set_handler(|| {
        // dropping will trigger ThreadPool::drop and gracefully shutdown the running workers
        drop(pool); // compile error, variable is moved here
    })
    .unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        pool.execute(|| {
            handle_connection(stream);
        });
    }
}
```

I tried multiple approaches with **Arc<>** and additional **mpsc channels**, but without success.

What is the best practice here in order to make it work?

Comment: There is perhaps a very different approach. When coding for Linux, I like to use `signalfd` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html, which results in signals turning up on a file descriptor rather than needing a registered handler. This makes life a lot easier, if you're handling other file descriptors in the app; one can use `select()` to wait for either a signal, or socket activity. You can also deal with the signal when you want to, not within an immediately-called handler. It's not portable though - I don't know if you're on Linux.

Comment: "I tried multiple approaches with Arc<> and additional mpsc channels, but without success." Well that's the way to go. Dropping the pool in the ctrl+c handler won't work - what if the main thread is still using it?

Comment: thx @bazza, I will have a look into this topic, but for now I settled with "good-enough" solution, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```rust
fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();
    let pool = ThreadPool::new(4);

    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    ctrlc::set_handler(move || tx.send(()).expect("Could not send signal on channel."))
        .expect("Error setting Ctrl-C handler");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        pool.execute(|| {
            handle_connection(stream);
        });

        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(_) => break,
            Err(_) => continue,
        }
    }
}
```

It has a flaw though. Namely after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the shutdown process is not triggered immediately, but only after receiving another request. Then the loop will break and the ThreadPool goes out of scope and gets dropped which triggers the graceful shutdown logic.

The solution is adequate for my learning purposes. In a production environment, one would rely on the graceful shutdown from a web-framework like [actix](https://actix.rs/)